# R's plm package equivalent for python/pyspark

Tags: python, r, pyspark, modeling, plm

Is there a Python or PySpark equivalent to R's `plm` package for models with fixed effects and random effects?

Answer (score 1):

There is a module called `linearmodels` for Python: https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/

It contains some model estimation procedures but does not seem as comprehensive regards test procedures.